# MONyog not show query?

Tags: mysql

I'm using MONyog to track all queries from user, but when config connect to mysql server. I can not see any query after click start? How can I see queries in MONyog?

Reference [MONyog](https://www.webyog.com/product/monyog)

Comment: add some code as well

Comment: MONyog is a software, reference is this link https://www.webyog.com/product/monyog

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are referring to MONyog's Real-Time feature? In Real-Time tab MONyog executes SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST at every 1 second to get queries being executed on the MySQL server. Hence, short-lived queries (queries which takes less than 1 second) may or may not be recorded.

You can enable Performance Schema based sniffer which will record all the queries(even short lived queries). Performance Schema based sniffer makes use of the performance_schema database of the MySQL server(which is available in v5.6+).

Comment: They have moved to v7 now. New GUI and all. [Monyog] (https://www.webyog.com/product/monyog)